# See only commits from a particular branch

Tags: mercurial

So, i made some work on the *default* branch, then i pushed those changes to my fork and after that i created a pull request from the fork to the parent repo (default branch at fork -> default branch at parent).

After this i created a *new branch*, made some changes, pushed them and again created a pull request from new branch on fork to new branch on parent.

In this pull request (new branch -> new branch) a see commits that are made in default->default pull request. But i expected to see only commits that i made in the new branch.

So, i want to see commits that i made to default in pull request to default and commits to new branch in the pull request made to this new branch. How do i make it?

I apologize for my awfull english. I tried my best to explain myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
hg log -r 'ancestor(default,pull_request_default)::pull_request_default'
```

replacing `pull_request_default` with the last revision of your pull request. It will only show the changesets of the pull request.